# After I deleted an iso file from ~/Downloads, I didn't get the disk space back

Tags: iso, disk-usage

I downloaded an ISO and mounted it, and it turned out to be the incorrect disk image.  I then unmounted it and deleted the `.iso` file from my `~/Downloads` folder (using the graphical shell).  However, I don't seem to have recovered any disk space.  What do I need to recover that space?  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Xfce4 on a Chromebook (which is why I need that space back).

Comment: Did you really delete it, or just move it to trash? if the latter, the space won't be recovered until you empty the trash

Comment: My trash folder is empty.  I find that on xfce4, certain types of files, when deleted using the file manager, don't even go to the trash.

Comment: I figured it out.  Within my ~/Downloads folder there is a hidden folder ".Trash-1000", in which things were going.  I have no idea how that is supposed to be managed, but I got my disk space back.

Comment: Write an answer.

Comment: Did you delete it from usb ?

Answer (score 1):

Within my `~/Downloads` folder there is a hidden folder `.Trash-1000`, to which deleted things were going. I have no idea how that is supposed to be managed, but I got my disk space back by deleting its contents.